# Browser Crashes with simple JS exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I've tried dubugging this line by line in the console and each line seems to work fine, but when I enter consequtive even numbers my browser freezes. It's probably obvious, but it's eluding me now. Code below:

```
$('body').append('<input type="number" id="myInput"><input type="submit" id="submit">');
$('#submit').click(function(){
        var myVal = $('#myInput').val();
        myArray = myVal.split("");
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length -1; i++){
            if((myArray[i]%2 == 0) && (myArray[i+1]%2 == 0)){
                myArray.splice(i,0,'-')
            }       
        }
        console.log(myArray);
});
```

Comment: Using `myArray.length` and then modifying said array in the loop is _very_ bad practice. If you keep pushing stuff to the array, when's `i` ever going to be `<` than `myArray.length`? Keep in mind that `myArray.lenght` is evaluated on each loop step.

Comment: Indeed, you keep pushing '-' into the array, so you run out of memory. Are you sure the logic you're looking for is: "When i is even and i+1 is also even, push the string minus sign into the array after i."

Comment: OK I see the poblem with using an increased array length in a loop counter...

Comment: Voodoo black magic alternative: `result = $('#myInput').val().replace(/([02468])(?=[02468])/,'$1-')`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need to do with this but this code works:

```
$('body').append('<input type="number" id="myInput"><input type="submit" id="submit">');
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var myVal = $('#myInput').val();
    myArray = myVal.split("");
    myArraylength = myArray.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < myArraylength; i++){
        if((myArray[i]%2 == 0) && (myArray[i+1]%2 == 0)){
            myArray.splice(i+1,0,'-')
        }
    }
    console.log(myArray);
});
```

Comment: This adds minus signs to the front, but my actual remit was to insert minus signs between even numbers.

Comment: Maybe it is better practice to start with an empty array and build it up conditionally?